# Installing pip packages in python file

Tags: python, pip

I do my project. I need to install pip packages in python code. But I get error.

If I try this:
`pip._internal.main(['install', package])` or this `pip.main(['install', package])` I get this:
`NameError: name 'pip' is not defined`. I use python 3.10 and pip 22. For do this code I use exec().

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Could you do something like this?

```py
import subprocess
import sys


def install_package(package):
    """
    Install a package using pip
    """

    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", package])
```

Comment: I need to install without "python" and "pip". I need use pyinstaller.

Comment: Why was pip used in the example you provided? Maybe I do not understand what you are trying to do.